# Using UNIX 'at' command to run shell script with arguments

Tags: php, shell, unix

I have a shell script that just cleans up a directory, but I want to call it inside my php code with an 'at' command.

I am having a problem with giving the at command arguments to its shell script that it's calling, so that it gives the shell script the correct file to delete.

```
shell_exec('at -f cleanup.sh $filename now + 30 minutes');
```

This fails and returns that it's a bad time specification.

This way works though...

```
shell_exec('at -f cleanup.sh now + 30 minutes');
```

It runs the at cleanup.sh at 30 minutes from now, but I lose the fact that I wanted to give the shell an argument so that it could delete a specific file.  The filename changes each time the program is run.

Comment: why not have a wrapper sh?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: `at -f cleanup.sh` "reads the job from file rather than standard input", it doesn't execute cleanup.sh, so you can't give it arguments. You may write a new cleanup.sh with the filename already embedded, as one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, my solution was using a wrapper sh.